YARP How to set up a reverse proxy for another full web server in a sub path?
I have a Qliksense server from domain and I have its certificate (.pfx) and I want to make a reverse proxy to it with ASP.NET Core + YARP.
The issue is when I set the proxy prefix as /qlik for example
and go to localhost/qlik, I get a http 404 error because the qlik server would read /qlik as a route and will try to fine the page that called qlik.
But when I remove the prefix of /qlik in the transform section
then go to localhost/qlik, the QlikSense server redirects me to another path called /hub, so it would be like localhost/qlik => localhost/hub
And this time my backend app itself is who would throw a 404 error because it will search of the /hub route which only exist on the QlikSense server and not my app
I need a dynamic way to make all of the QlikSense paths be of sub path /qlik
Like it should be when I go to localhost/qlik => localhost/qlik/hub and the qliksense server would read the path as /hub not /qlik/hub
Is there any way to do this?
I heard about something in the transformation like:
{
    "ResponseHeader": "Location",
    "Set": "{Scheme}://{Host}/qlik{Headers.Location}",
    "When": "Response"
}

but I get an error, not sure if I'm using it correctly.
I expect to get a solution to handle make a reverse proxy that reverse all of the qliksense routes and resources in a sub path

You can try to modify the request path and remove the prefix value by using PathRemovePrefix in Transforms. Here is an example for your reference:
{
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "qlikRoute": {
        "ClusterId": "qlikCluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/qlik/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathRemovePrefix": "/qlik"
          },
          {
            "ResponseHeader": "Location",
            "Set": "{Scheme}://{Host}/qlik{Headers.Location}",
            "When": "Success"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "qlikCluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "qlikServer": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:7007/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

When I enter https://localhost:7061/qlik/hub in the URL, it will jump to the target address correctly.



it should be https://localhost:7061/qlik then it will redirect u to https://localhost:7061/qlik/hub
check this screenshot: https://ibb.co/Sd3zFTM
